# C: How can I read a huge amount integers of a file into a huge enough array?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program to read csv files containing only ints. The problem I'm facing is some of the files contain about 1000000 different numbers and thus an array is too small to store all the numbers. The code I have written reads the file successfully but does not store the correct integers and only repeats one number. Can someone please help me correct my mistake that would be greatly appreciated.

```
FILE *file;
file = fopen(filename, "r");

int *list;
int count = 0;                // count the numbers in the file 

printf("\t- Readed %d numbers\n", count);

list = ( int* ) malloc( count * sizeof(int) );       // create momary 

if( !(list = ( int* ) malloc( count * sizeof(int) )))
{
    printf("\tMemory allocation failed\n\n");
}
else
{
    printf("\tMemory allocation suceeded\n\n");
}

// scanning content into array

int i;
for( i = 0; i < count; i++ )
{
    fscanf( file, "%d,", &list[i] );
    printf( "%d\n", list[i] );
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: What is `&[list]` ?? Does it work for small files? Somehow I doubt it

Comment: Maybe try `fscanf( file, "%d,", &(list[i]) );`

Comment: You are allocating 0 integers with `count=0;`.  Not gonna work well.  Figure out what count is and set the variable correctly.

Comment: How are the numbers stored in file (one number per line or somehow )?

Comment: Vida Ras "and only repeats one number." --> and was that the expect first number?  What was seen?  What was expected.?

Answer (score 0):

Various troubles

**Allocation for only 0 `int`**  [@Michael Dorgan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61529113/c-how-can-i-read-a-huge-amount-integers-of-a-file-into-a-huge-enough-array/61531720#comment108840693_61529113)

```
// int count = 0;
#define N  1000000
int count = N;
```

**Wrong null test**

OP is allocating again, losing access to the first allocation.

```
// if( !(list = ( int* ) malloc( count * sizeof(int) )))
if (list == NULL)
```

**No `fscanf()` check**

```
// fscanf( file, "%d,", &list[i] );
if (fscanf( file, "%d,", &list[i] ) != 1) break;
```

**Clean-up**

```
// add after the loop
fclose(file);
```

---

Other

**Simplify code**

```
// list = ( int* ) malloc( count * sizeof(int) );       // create momary 
list = malloc(sizeof *list * count);
```

**Debug**

Add a print to find how much was read.

```
// after the loop
printf("i: %d\n", i);
```